# Customize header of "Create <content type>"

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

When you create content on Drupal, the header at the top says "Create ". On certain content-types I don't want it to say that. Is there a way to customize that header on certain content-types and keep it as-is on others?

thanks.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+theming+form

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360229/changing-cck-title-for-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try drupal_set_title?

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_title/6

I believe you can do this by writing a simple module, calling mymodule_form_alter(), checking the path (for instance, so it only happens on a Page type as opposed to a Blog type), then using drupal_set_title('Custom title') to change it.

If that happens 'too late' in the process, try it with mymodule_init().

You can also look at the String Overrides module.